# How to fix Spring Security jdbc Authentication

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to set up custom authentication inside my own small project. I've set up my database (PostgreSQL) and tried to login using data from database (login admin, password admin, authority ROLE_ADMIN), but I'm getting error while loging in (and then app keeps redirecting me to login page). Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
                            @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout,
                            Model model) {

        String errorMessge = null;

        if(error != null) {
            errorMessge = "Username or Password is incorrect!";
        }
        if(logout != null) {
            errorMessge = "You have been successfully logged out!";
        }
        model.addAttribute("errorMessge", errorMessge);

        return "login";
    }
```

WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, enabled from users where username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, authority from authorities where username=?");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/userAccount")
                .hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "ROLE_ADMIN", "USER", "ROLE_USER")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/userAccount")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout=true")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable();
    }
```

User entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private boolean enabled;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(int id, String username, String password, boolean enabled) {

        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

Could it have something to do with database schemas or something?

Comment: What error do you get? Please include stack trace, if there is one.

Comment: There is no stack trace. It keeps redirecting me to login?error=true (defined as failureUrl in configuration) with error set as true.

Comment: @marty007 What password did you save in your database? What password encoder did you use?

Comment: I saved login admin and password admin. Didn't encode my password at all. Is encoding always required?

Comment: Ok problem solved - I used BCryptPasswordEncoder and stored not encrypted password in database - thus password was not correct when I tried to type it into password input.